# Magento 2: How to remove zoom on hover on product image in view page?

Tags: magento2, zoom

How do I remove the **zoom feature** on hover on the image in product view page.

This is a standard magento function apparently.

Comment: Provide some more details!

Comment: It is a standard magento 2 function, `magnifier.js` and `magnify.js` come with magento 2

Answer (score 3):

In the module `Magento_Catalog` there is the `jquery.zoom.min.js` file.
Just set the `magnify` property to 0.

```
(function ($) {
var defaults = {
    url: false,
    callback: false,
    target: false,
    duration: 120,
    on: 'grab', // other options: grab, click, toggle
    touch: true, // enables a touch fallback
    onZoomIn: false,
    onZoomOut: false,
    magnify: 0
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to override `etc/view.xml` and change this code.

```
<var name="gallery">
    <var name="allowfullscreen">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off fullscreen (true/false) -->
    ...
</var>
```

or you can also use this.

```
<var name="magnifier">
   <var name="enabled">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (true/false) -->
</var>
```

May be it will help you.

Comment: I have tried both of these. When you disable magnifier, the lightbox does not show when you click the image. But the product on hover zoom is still there.

Comment: have you install third party extension for hover zoom?