# Zoom Image change on mouse over

Tags: magento2.3, product-images, products, zoom

I want to change the product image Zoom on mouse hover on product page.

```
<var name="magnifier">
            <var name="fullscreenzoom">20</var>  <!-- Zoom for fullscreen (integer)-->
            <var name="top"></var> <!-- Top position of magnifier -->
            <var name="left"></var> <!-- Left position of magnifier -->
            <var name="width"></var> <!-- Width of magnifier block -->
            <var name="height"></var> <!-- Height of magnifier block -->
            <var name="eventType">hover</var> <!-- Action that atcivates zoom (hover/click) -->
            <var name="enabled">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (true/false) -->
            <var name="mode">outside</var> <!-- Zoom type (outside/inside) -->
        </var>
```

I am using above code but it's not working.

Comment: check this link - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/149508/85907

Comment: Where you implement this code? Have you run all the commands after above change?

Comment: I run all the commands

Comment: @Dhiren override etc/view.xml and change the code.

Comment: Product Zoom on mouse hover instead of remove zoom